# Security implications of wide WAN subnet

Tags: security, subnet, gateway, wide-area-network

I have a server at OVH and say my public IP adress is xx.xx.xx.81 and the gateway is at xx.xx.xx.254.

To reach the gateway, I need pfSense to be configured static WAN IP with xx.xx.xx.81/24, i.e. the whole subnet, allthough all other servers on that subnet are not mine.

What are the security implications of leaving the WAN subnet at /24 instead of /32 with a static route to the gateway? Could this setup "disturb" other users in that subnet? Is a static route in any way "more efficient"?

Comment: Are you certain that the provider has given you a /24? It seems more likely that they'd give you a /28 or a /29. If they've given you a /28 or a /29 then that's what you'd configure as the subnet mask (255.255.255.240 or 255.255.255.248) and configure the pfSense with an appropriate ip address in the subnet.

Comment: There isn't one. This configuration is correct for the fixed physical IP assigned to your server (not the failover IPs).

Comment: @MichaelHampton okay, are you sure? I understand that this configuration probably has no impact on security as its on the other side of the firewall anyway, but how about performance. Is there any broadcast traffic i could cut of by using a /32 subnet with a static route? I'm asking because i constantly get blocked stuff on my firewall logs from the other servers on the subnet.
joeqwerty they have given me a single IP of the /24 subnet i.e. a /32, never said otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to the Internet.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks, but I'd hoped for a more detailed answer. There must be a reason for OVH to ask their customers to use a /32 configuraiton "to limit their broadcast"?

Comment: People tend to install noisy stuff on their servers which broadcasts to the local network. Provided you're firewalled properly, this really isn't an issue. And the "/32" configuration really isn't reliable, at least OVH has never provided a working configuration example, so you have to live with it anyway.

Comment: Okay I'm satisfied, feel free to post it as an answer to close of this Q.